# Is there any simple wordpress search template that works with existing searchforms?

Tags: plugins, templates, search

I want to replace my theme's search functionality with new functionality that searches trough text widgets. Almost all content of my site is provided trough text widgets (they are static pages).

Is there any default wordpress search template that I can use and that will work with my existing search forms?

In regards to Toscho's questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159520/wordpress-perform-a-search-on-widget-text/):

1. My site doesn't have that much content, so slowness is not a problem.
2. Search results may point to a specific page, the page that hosts the widget
3. I want only to display results from text widgets.

Comment: I am not sure how item #2 is supposed to work. You have page specific widgets?

Comment: Yes. Each page has a set of textwidgets that display the content. Like this: http://piclair.com/data/6w5ru.jpg

Comment: You are doing this the long and hard way. This is _really_ not the way widgets are intended to be used. You are going to be fighting the whole WordPress superstructure starting with how you associate widgets with a page in the first place (which is information necessary to even start thinking about an answer).

Comment: Well, the problem is that I have a different design for each and every page of my site. These widgets can also contain html and shortcodes and are thus part of the design. I don't know any other way to do that.

Comment: Well, custom meta boxes and CPTs come to mind, but you haven't described your actual project much.

Comment: I'm developing a site for a startup company that sells logo's and corporate branding styles. I've to implement a complete custom design that is difficult to implement if using standard wordpress features or plugins. They often lack the required customization. I do have custom headers and footer templates, but for the actual page content these widgets where the easiest solution. But I agree with you that it is impractical. If you know any better solution that I use for future projects, then I am all ears :)

Comment: But for this site it is too late to change the design process. Is there really no solution at all for searching trough text widgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widget content is stored in the `$wpdb->options` table as serialized data. You can search that with SQL because to SQL serialized data is just a string.

```
SELECT option_value FROM {$wpdb->options} WHERE meta_value LIKE "something"
```

But...

- The table is not indexed for that kind of search
- Searching serialized data is dicey anyway
- And I have no idea how you are going to associate the widgets with
  the pages. That does no happen by default and you have not answered
  my question about that point.

Put together you aren't going to have a very efficient query and once you jump through hoops to associate the widgets and pages/posts it is going to be even less efficient still.

Sorry, but the decision to build the site the way you have was badly flawed.